# How can I convert a string to an array of chars?

Tags: arrays, string, char, c99

So I want to get a string into an array of characters, but the thing is i need to define the array length before i can get chars into it but i dont know what the length would be because it depends on the string the user inputs, is there a way?
I'm programming in C99 standard.

Comment: Get the string first. Then you'll know its length. So then you can put it into a char array.

Comment: but then i wont have the string anymore.... because i get it length with getchar and when it will reach then end i cant get the string

Comment: IMO Schwartz's comment is your best option.Just save the length of the string somewhere else with another variable. Remember, you control the flow of your programs so, the string disappear only when you get rip of the string.

Comment: Also, (I know you explicitly said C99) you could always use `getline()` which is POSIX, very portable.

Answer (score 2):

Most people solve this by just making an array large enough to handler their biggest ever expected input ( or well over ).

But in a situation where you have no way of knowing the number of characters you are going to get and want to handle it,  then you need to dynamically grow the memory through memory allocations  ( using some kind of log based growth).  ie,   allocated 100 chars, if you try adding more ,  dynamically allocate 200, copy what you already have, then add on the new stuf.   Then if you hit 200,  again, allocate again to 400, and copy, add.  (actual numbers just made up)

Comment: pointers just point to things.  you need a pointer to a chunk of memory that can hold all the data.    To get a pointer to a chunk of memory that can hold your data you need to dynamically allocate it (malloc).

Comment: if that chunk of memory fills up, you then need to get a bigger chunk of memory,  copy all the stuff you already had to the bigger chunk, then add on more

Comment: Use `realloc()` to grow the string. It returns a new pointer.